# How can I "lazily" read output from xrandr?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, display-settings

I have a bash script that I use to adjust my monitor brightness that uses `xrandr --verbose` to get the current brightness. It works fine, but using `xrandr` is kind of slow on my machine, as you can see here:

```
[PROMPT REDACTED]$ time xrandr --verbose
# xrandr output omitted for brevity
real    0m0.976s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.002s
```

This outputs lots of information that I don't need, in addition to taking almost a full second. The only line out of the output that I actually need is `Brightness: X`. I am currently using this line to get the value from it:

```
BRIGHTNESS=`xrandr --verbose | grep -i brightness | cut -f2 -d ' ' | head -n1`
```

*Side note: `head` is called at the end because I have 2 monitors, so I end up with 2 values, but only need 1, since I am keeping them both at the same brightness.*

Since I only need that one line from `xrandr --verbose`, I was wondering if there is a way I could "lazily" evaluate it, by doing something like:

- Stopping `xrandr` outputting once it reaches that line
- Ignoring the rest of the output from `xrandr` once I have read that line
- Something else?

I realize bash may not be the language best suited for this, so I am open to solutions in other languages as well.

Comment: Can you use one of `xbacklight -get` or `cat` the appropriate file in `/sys/class/backlight`?

Comment: I have just installed `xbacklight`, and `xbacklight -get` outputs `No outputs have backlight property`. I have no files in `/sys/class/backlight` either.

Comment: `xrandr` executes in 0.084s for me :x

Comment: @Populus `xrandr` or `xrandr --verbose`? Just `xrandr` only takes about ~.080s for me

Comment: xrandr is [open source](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xrandr/tree/xrandr.c).  It shouldn't be terribly difficult to modify the source to make your own program that only queries the brightness.  That's sort of the nuclear option, though.

Comment: `time xrandr --verbose` gives `real 0m0.083s` `time xrandr` gives around the same runtime as well... and before you say something is wrong, `time xrandr --verbose | grep -i brightness` gives me the desired result, and has a runtime of `0.085s`. And incase it's useful, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I'm not sure what would cause it, but `time xrandr` gives me `real 0m0.080s`, while `time xrandr --verbose` gives `real 0m0.797s`. I am running Scientific Linux, which may be part of the problem. (I think Scientific Linux is always part of the problem.)

Comment: @gla3dr - again, that is a *significant* difference and must be directly related to the kernel's pipe buffer - which explains the dramatic success of `stdbuf` in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try and stop and ignore upon the first find of `brigthness`. From `grep` man page:

```
 -m NUM, --max-count=NUM
          Stop  reading  a  file after NUM matching lines.
```

This is my final version. Note that we don't even need the `head`:

```
BRIGHTNESS=`xrandr --verbose | grep -m 1 -i brightness | cut -f2 -d ' '`
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. It's a little faster now. Not quite as fast as I had hoped though.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `awk` to remove some pipelines (processes) and to only read the file until encountering the first instance of Brightness:

```
xrandr --verbose | awk '/Brightness/ { print $2; exit }'
```

Comment: Looks like `awk` is indeed a little faster than `grep` and `cut`. Thanks!

Comment: Combined with the `stdbuf -o0` trick in my answer, this is the fastest solution here. +1

Comment: @paraxor - not anymore. By my tests the `sed` solution in my own answer and the `awk` solution here present no difference in execution time - and I also have two displays, so the `q` makes a significant difference. Each runs at .03 to .04 seconds at every execution - and the addition of `stdbuf` only slows them down. But `xgamma` is faster still.

Comment: @mikeserv adding `stdbuf` seems to be crucial on my machine. Using @jasonwryan's solution exactly (no stdbuf), I got `real 0m0.728s`. Adding `stdbuf` to it gave me `real 0m0.126s`. However, using your `sed` solution along with `stdbuf` as opposed to `awk` seems to consistently give me another .006s.

Comment: @gla3dr - I will agree that is crucial. Was that run from a script or the terminal? And was that with line-buffered utils like `sed` and/or `awk` or was it using `cut`?

Comment: @mikeserv That was in the terminal and using awk.

Comment: @gla3dr - weird. I wonder why the effect is so significant? Anyway, thanks very much for following that up.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @LatinSuD's suggestion of using `grep`'s `-m` flag to stop reading after a match, you can adjust the size of `xrandr`'s stdout buffer with a tool like [`stdbuf`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman1/stdbuf.1.html) like so:

```
BRIGHTNESS=`stdbuf -o0 xrandr --verbose | grep -m 1 -i brightness | cut -f2 -d ' '`
```

This can give you a significant speed increase:

```
$ cat brightness
xrandr --verbose | grep -m 1 -i brightness | cut -f2 -d ' '

$ time sh brightness > /dev/null
sh brightness > /dev/null  0.00s user 0.00s system 1% cpu 0.485 total

$ cat brightness_nobuffer
stdbuf -o0 xrandr --verbose | grep -m 1 -i brightness | cut -f2 -d ' '

[ para ~ . ]$ time sh brightness_nobuffer > /dev/null
sh brightness_nobuffer > /dev/null  0.01s user 0.01s system 10% cpu 0.130 total
```

Answer (score 2):

The slowest step is: `xrandr --verbose`. So if you didn't have to fetch brightness using `xrandr --verbose` every time you try adjusting your brightness, the problem will be solved.

This can be achieved by the following workflow:

1. Export the current brightness one-time (preferably, at start-up) using: `` echo `xrandr --verbose | grep -m 1 -i brightness | cut -f2 -d ' '` > brightness.txt ``
2. And every time you need the brightness read it from `brightness.txt`
3. And every time you update the brightness also update the value at `brightness.txt`

For example this is how I update my brightness:

```
#!/bin/bash

# BRIGHT=`xrandr --verbose | grep -m 1 -i brightness | cut -f2 -d ' '`

BRIGHT=`cat brightness.txt`

if [ "$1" = '+' ]; then
    NEWBRIGHT=$(echo "$BRIGHT + 0.05" | bc)
    if [ "$(echo "$NEWBRIGHT > 1.0" | bc)" -eq 1 ]; then
        NEWBRIGHT='1.0'
    fi
elif [ "$1" = '-' ]; then
    NEWBRIGHT=$(echo "$BRIGHT - 0.05" | bc)
    if [ "$(echo "$NEWBRIGHT < 0.0" | bc)" -eq 1 ]; then
        NEWBRIGHT='0.0'
    fi
fi

xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness "$NEWBRIGHT"
echo "${NEWBRIGHT}" > brightness.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you install the `xbacklight` program.

Of course, if your hardware does not support it, this is not an option. So you must resort to the software adjustment as you have been doing:

```
man xrandr 2>/dev/null |
grep '^ *--brightness' -A8
   --brightness brightness
          Multiply the gamma values on the  crtc  cur‐
          rently  attached  to the output to specified
          floating value. Useful for overly bright  or
          overly  dim  outputs.   However,  this  is a
          software only modification, if your hardware
          has  support  to actually change the bright‐
          ness, you will probably prefer to use xback‐
          light.
```

It would appear that the brightness settting is nothing more than a multiplier for the RGB *gamma* values of your display. As such, it might make more sense - or, at least, it may be easier - if you instead directly affected that with `xgamma`.

```
xgamma
-> Red  1.000, Green  1.000, Blue  1.000

xgamma -gamma .7
-> Red  1.000, Green  1.000, Blue  1.000
<- Red  0.700, Green  0.700, Blue  0.700
```

In the same vein as many other answers you can quit the input with `sed` as soon as you encounter a *Brightness* string like:

```
xrandr --verbose | sed '/Br/!d;s/.* //;q'
```

That deletes all lines before the first occurrence of the *Br* string. When it finds one it then removes everything up to and including the last `<space>` from the line before immediately quitting the input. So all that remains in a case of 100% brightness is, for instance:

```
echo "<$(xrandr --verbose | sed '/Br/!d;s/.* //;q')>"
<1.0>
```

It would be far better though if you could get a valid EDID on your output and directly affect its backlight with the following tool:

```
man xbacklight 2>/dev/null | 
sed '/^ *SYNOPSIS/,/^ *-inc/!d;//c\\'

       xbacklight [-help]  [-display display] [-get] [-set
       percent] [-inc percent] [-dec percent]

DESCRIPTION
       Xbacklight  is used to adjust the backlight bright‐
       ness where supported. It finds all outputs on the X
       server  supporting backlight brightness control and
       changes them all in the same way.

       -get   Print out the current  backlight  brightness
              of  each  output  with  such  a control. The
              brightness is represented as a percentage of
              the maximum brightness supported.

       -set percent
              Sets each backlight brightness to the speci‐
              fied level.
```

It is apparently already installed on my machine because, at some point I installed...

```
pacman -Qo /usr/bin/xbacklight
/usr/bin/xbacklight is owned by xorg-xbacklight 1.2.1-1
```

...^that package.

Comment: See second comment on question. Any ideas on how to solve that issue?

Comment: I'm sorry @gla3dr - I did not see that. I'll look into it. It maybe to do with `xset` and DPMS. Also - what kind of connection do you have between monitor/computer? HDMI/DVI?

Comment: I have `Monitor -> DVI -> VGA adapter -> Computer`

Comment: @gla3dr Oh, then, yes, I have an idea how you might solve it. I suggest you do *Monitor -> DVI -> Computer* - is this possible?

Comment: Looks like I was slightly wrong about that. I have 2 DVIs (one from each monitor) going into a DMS-59 Y-adapter. That is what is going into my computer.

Comment: @gla3dr - Well, this is all a little outside my own purview, but I figure that if you're having difficulty directly affecting a screen's settings and that screen is connected to a splitter there may be some correlation. In any case - do you see the update? Does `xgamma` work?

Comment: xgamma sort of works, but I can only get it to change 1 monitor. Do you know what I need to give the `-screen` flag to be able to specify a monitor?

Comment: @gla3dr - did you try `xgamma -screen`?

Comment: `xgamma -screen` just outputs the "usage" message.

Comment: @gla3dr - I'm sorry. You have to use the `-screen` number like `xgamma -screen 0 -gamma .8` or something. You can get the screen numbers like `xrandr |grep '^Screen:'`. You don't need verbosity. On my machine I have only one *logical* screen running both monitors and so `xgamma` automatically affects both. I expect your situation is opposite.

Answer (score 0):

As xbacklight was not working for me I adapt previous answer to make a script which could be called as keyboard shortcut :

```
#!/bin/bash
bright=$(xrandr --verbose | awk '/Brightness/ { print $2; exit }')
case $1 in
up)
xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness $(echo $bright+0.1 |bc -l)
;;
down)
xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness $(echo $bright-0.1 |bc -l)
;;
*)
echo error
exit 1
;;
esac
```