# how to use dd to fill drive with 1's

Tags: dd

Filling a drive with `/dev/urandom` seems to be very slow, so I created a file filled with `FF`:

```
dd if=/dev/zero ibs=1k count=1000 | tr "\000" "\377" >ff.bin
```

I'd like to fill the drive with copies of this file but the following command only writes once:

```
dd if=ff.bin of=/dev/sdb count=10000
```

How do I fill the drive with copies of the file, or is there a faster way to fill the drive with **1**'s?

Comment: Why not use zeros? 1-bits don't erase a disk better than 0-bits.

Comment: @Gilles I guess zero is special enough that the disk driver could cheat and not really write anything to disk, only marking blocks as empty. I think some virtual hard disk do so. But still, it depends on which reason he's filling a drive for. If it is security, neither 0 nor 1 are safe enough, and also filling with random wouldn't be good if the hard disk is SSD

Comment: @pqnet Zero isn't special for physical storage. With a virtual hard disk, it might be, but filling with anything is unsafe. For SSD, there are specific issues with reallocated blocks, but writing with nonzero values doesn't help with that.

Comment: @Gilles well, the reason for which he want to write to his disk is not explained so I think it would be great if the question is clarified

Comment: The venerable `dd` has a the option `seek=N skip N obs-sized blocks at start of output`, so you can write a loop to seek to the correct place `k*M` on the output block device before repeating a write of the M-sized file.

Answer (score 18):

Simply do:

```
tr '\0' '\377' < /dev/zero > /dev/sdb
```

It will abort with an error when the drive is full.

Using `dd` does not make sense here.  You use `dd` to make sure reads and writes are made of a specific size. There's no reason to do it here. `tr` will do reads/writes of 4 or 8 kiB which should be good enough.

Comment: you might even get a boost with `tr ... | tee - - - > /dev/disk` but the likelihood that `tr` alone doesn't already meet and exceed the write bottleneck is pretty slim.

Comment: @mikeserv, I think the only way to increase performance from that is to reduce the number of system calls made. `tee` won't help for that. `stdbuf -o1M tr...` may help.

Comment: Agreed. I sometimes use `/dev/zero` as a bucket with `tr` - like for newlines or whatever - and it always consumes a whole cpu. I think the pull from the kernel pumping out all of those bytes is pretty heavy. I was thinking that perhaps the file could just be duped. Maybe it was dumb.

Comment: @mikeserv, actually, using `tee - - -` does increase throughput significantly in my testing. That's going from 800MiB/s for `tr` (950MiB/s with stdbuf) to 2.3GiB/s with tee, like you say in any case way above the rate any current drive can sustain.

Comment: Maybe true, but that 2.3g flood will still wind up trickling as soon your pipeline steps outside of job control. `stdbuf` is smart - I never use it and probably should. And this is the [second time](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150816/how-can-i-lazily-read-output-from-xrandr/150828?noredirect=1#comment245856_150828) in as many days someone's brought that to my attention. I think the other thing is CentOS - I read somewhere about a 64kb kernel buffer.

Comment: @mikeserv, the pipes are 64kB large on current versions of Linux, that may be where you got that 64kB from.

Comment: you're a funny guy sometimes

Comment: sorry, how come you pass in `'\0' '\377'`?  Is it necessary?  Thanks!

Comment: @HCSF Those are the parameters to the `tr` command. `tr` `tr`anslates characters - in this case `\0` to `\377` - both are octal numbers. `/dev/null` spews out constant `\0` and `tr` is used to translate that stream into constant `\377`.  377 in octal is the same as 0xff in hexadecimal.

Comment: Dear @mikeserv @StéphaneChazelas , as we are only writing to one file `/dev/sdb`, stdout is not necessary, I do not understand why we need `tee`, and why `tee` would boost the speed?

Comment: @midnite, the point would be that some implementations of `tr` are slow to translate 0s to 1s, and tee would reuse the output of tr several times so `tr` would have to translate fewer 0s into 1s. The extreme version of that would likely be the fastest one: compute one large buffer full of 1s in memory once, and write that over and over.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, Thank you very much for explanations. May I ask to the complete script would be `tr '\0' '\377' < /dev/zero | tee - - - - - - > /dev/sdb`? And the more the dashes in `tee`, it will be theoretically faster? How did you measure the speeds? I would like to add `pv` to show progress. Should I just add `pv` in front of the script? On the other hand, I did suspect `tr` translation may be slow. If we could use `\377` directly, we do not need translation at all. May be `printf '\377' | tee - - - - - - - > /dev/sdb` in concept?

Answer (score 5):

For a faster `/dev/urandom` alternative, there is `shred -v -n 1` (if pseudorandom is OK), or using `cryptsetup` with random key and zeroing that (for encrypted zeroes). Even without AES acceleration, it easily beats `/dev/urandom` speeds.

Not sure how fast `tr` is, otherwise you could just `dd if= | tr | dd of=`.

Using a file as a pattern source could be done like this:

```
(while [ 1 ]; do cat file; done) | dd of=...
```

Although the file should be reasonably large for that to be remotely efficient.

If the `count=` is important to you, add `iflag=fullblock` to the `dd` command. Partial reads are possible which would result in partial blocks to be counted as full blocks. This is especially when using larger blocksizes (like `bs=1M`), which you should if you want speed.

Comment: shred is fast, and it reports progress!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I am editing my answer here as I came across a boot disc that didn't even have AWK available (just dd and tr were my only familiar friends available):

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=65536 | tr '\0' '\377' | dd of=/dev/sda bs=65536
```

I found it necessary for speed/performance reasons to choose a 64 kB block size for my disk drive.

The performance of the above command was equal to my first pass of `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=65536` (took about 37 minutes to fill a 75 GiB ATA disk drive, ~35 MiB/s)

Comment: But there are no forks?

Comment: David, just the single fork to execute AWK, then the control statement loop and printf are function calls of the AWK programming language.

Comment: fwiw, on my system awk was complaining of a line too long, until I made it 8192 char long instead of 65536

Answer (score 4):

```
badblocks -v -w -s -b physical block size -t 0xff /dev/the device
```

Example to write all `ff` to 4K native HDD at `/dev/sdb` plus read it back to verify `ff` was actually written to every block:

```
$ sudo badblocks -v -w -s -b 4096 -t 0xff /dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 0):

To test the SSD speed, I wrote a little Perl program to write "zeros", "ones" or alphanumerics to a block device given on the command line. It doesn't invoke the `dd` golem, just does direct writes and syncs. May be of help here:

https://github.com/dtonhofer/wild_block_device_filler

Just run it as

```
wildly_fill_block_device.pl --dev=sdX1 --fillpat 1 --chunksize=1024P --sync
```

And it will write 0xFFs to /dev/sdX1 (unbuffered, using Perl's syswrite()) in chunks of (in this case) "1024 physical blocks" while synch-ing the data to disk after every write using fdatasync(). On my SSD, this runs at ~70 MiB/s.

It will ask you whether you are SURE before it proceeds to nuke the partition or disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty efficiently in Bash without external files, except the device to write to, or external commands, except `dd`.

1. Use `printf` to generate a byte with all one bits, and put it in a Bash variable.
2. Concatenate the Bash variable to itself multiple times.
3. Use Bash process substitution to fake an infinitely long input file that repeatedly `echo`es the Bash variable with no trailing newline.
4. Use that as the input file to `dd`.

If you have GNU `dd`, get a nice progress bar with:

```
sudo -i
bash
ones="$( printf '\xff' )"; for _ in {1..16}; do ones="$ones$ones"; done; dd status=progress bs=65536 if=<( while true; do echo -n "$ones"; done ) of=/dev/whatever
```

Remove the `status=progress` if it doesn't work for you. The `65536` is 2<sup>16</sup>, because the initial byte with all one bits was duplicated `16` times.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a `/dev/one` without a special device, with a FIFO + `yes`:

```
mkfifo ddfifo
dd if=ddfifo of=<file> iflag=fullblock bs=32K status=progress & yes "" | tr '\n' '\1' > ddfifo
```

`tee` may be used to double the throughput:

```
mkfifo ddfifo
dd if=ddfifo of=<file> iflag=fullblock bs=4M status=progress & yes "" | tr '\n' '\1' | tee ddfifo > ddfifo
```

If you'd like bytes with all bits set to one, swap `'\1'` for `'\377'`.

Answer (score -2):

How to wipe with 1's:

```
while true; do echo 1 ; done | dd of=/dev/sdX status=progress
```

How to test the wipe:

```
dd if=/dev/sdX count=1 bs=512
```

Comment: That's actually filling with pairs of characters, ASCII/unicode `1` and the subsequent newline. As an aside, you can replace the `while` loop with `yes 1` - but it doesn't address the requirement to fill the drive with the binary bytes `0000001`