# How do I create binary file with certain value?

Tags: shell-script, dd, binary

I need to create a binary file that is filled only with `11111111`.

I only know how to create zero-filled binary with

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=18520 count=1
```

Could you please say to me what a command in pipeline should I use to fill the bin with `1`? How can I use `awk` in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use dd to fill drive with 1's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150988/how-to-use-dd-to-fill-drive-with-1s)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably easiest to use `tr` to convert the zeroes from `/dev/zero` to whatever you want, and then cut to length using `dd` or `head` or such.

This would write 18520 bytes with all bits ones, so value 0xff or 255, or 377 in octal as the input must be:

```
< /dev/zero tr '\000' '\377' | head -c 18520 > test.bin
```

(To convert from hex or decimal to octal, you could use `printf "%o\n" 0xff` or such. )

---

To produce streams of longer than one-byte strings, I'd use Perl:

```
perl -e '$a = "abcde" x 1024; print $a while 1' | head ...
```

(Of course you could use `"\xff"` or `"\377"` there, too. I used the repetition operator `x 1024` there mostly to avoid minimally small writes. Changing it may or may not affect the performance of that.)

Comment: @DisplayName: for string abcde without using perl, use yes: `yes "abcde" | tr -d '\n' ` ...

Comment: @OlivierDulac, d'oh, I've really been slow here. Using `yes` actually crossed my mind before, but I got stuck at the mandatory newline... `yes $'\xff' | tr -d '\n' | ...` would also work for the all-ones in shells that support `$''`.

Comment: I'd certainly not qualify you as slow ^^. And having different options (suxh as perl) is always welcomed. Feel free to add the yes variant as well if you want.

Comment: It's (very) slightly more efficient to `head` or `dd` first in the pipe, then `tr` after.

Answer (score 14):

[Don't use `dd bs=…`: it isn't reliable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial). Either use `ibs=1 obs=1` or use less error-prone tools. Most `head` implementations can count bytes:

```
</dev/zero head -c 18520
```

If you want a file filled with a single byte other than zero, change the byte value with `tr`. For all-bits-one:

```
</dev/zero head -c 18520 | tr '\0' '\377'
```

Answer (score 3):

to answer your question specifically, using dd will work great with tr in a pipe

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=18520 count=1 | tr '\000' '1' > test.bin
```

however, you should clarify the scope of this in order for one to give you a more relevant answer

Comment: `1` is ascii character `1`, `0x31`, so the file will be filled with bits `00110001` repeated.